# Find the $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1^2}{n^3+1^3} + \frac{2^2}{n^3+2^3} + \cdots + \frac{n^2}{n^3+n^3}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Find the $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1^2}{n^3+1^3} +
>  \frac{2^2}{n^3+2^3} + \cdots + \frac{n^2}{n^3+n^3}$

I've attempted to find the following: 
$$\frac{1^2}{n^3+1^3} +
 \frac{2^2}{n^3+2^3} + \cdots + \frac{n^2}{n^3+n^3} = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac {i^2}{n^3+i^3}$$

However, I'm stuck at finding a formula for $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac {i^2}{n^3+i^3}$ as i don't think it's possible to get a geometric sequence formula for $\frac {1}{i}$.

Comment: Consider $\int _{0}^{1} \frac{x^2}{1+x^3} dx$

Comment: @samjoe how did you deduce that the interval would be [0,1]?

Comment: Refer Robert Z's answer below. Basically its a riemann sum. The limits of integration are $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{k}{n}$ for $k = 1$ and $k = n$ as these are first and last terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Note that
$$\frac{1^2}{n^3+1^3} + \frac{2^2}{n^3+2^3} + \cdots + \frac{n^2}{n^3+n^3}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(k/n)^2}{1+(k/n)^3}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n f(k/n).$$
where $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{1+x^3}$.
So here we have the [Riemann sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum) of $f$ over $[0,1]$ and 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n f(k/n)=\int_0^1f(t)dt.$$

Comment: hi i've further expanded the summation to $\frac {k^2}{k^3+n^3}$, and have no idea how should i work the limit. Any idea?

Comment: Recall the definition of Riemann sum: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum